# Jquery help repeated ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I submit my form, a repeated ajax call is made it never stop.

Here is my Jquery for the ajax call on form submit:

```
$('form#formgo').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#comparecontent').empty().html(
        '<p style="text-align:center;">' +
        '<img src="../images/ajax.gif" /></p>');

    var form = $(this).closest('form');

    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
            $('#comparecontent').html(msg);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by endless, does it never succeed, or does the request repeat over and over again?

Comment: Does it ever reach the 2nd line?

Comment: #1 - It just keep making the ajax call (POST) and renders the html content

Answer (score 3):

In your ajax call, try specifying a `timeout` for the request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        timeout: 3000, // time in milliseconds
        success:function(msg){
$('#comparecontent').html(msg);
    }
});
```

see the `.ajax()` documentation for more info on available params http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The timeout does not stop all the repeated ajax calls

Comment: Ah, "endless" and "repeated" are 2 different things. If possible, please provide a link to your page so the community can examine the issue first hand.

Comment: I mean repeated ajax call, the page is not online

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something is triggering submit. 
Try [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$('form#formgo').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...
```

Also check if an `onchange` event is bound to elements with id `comparecontent`.